# Publish Related Items not working with Sitecore SPS on scale environment

Tags: publishing-service

I am using `Sitecore 9.3` with `SPS 4.2`. Publish is working fine but "Publish Related Items" is not working. After digging into some documents and Sitecore Support I came to know that I need to change the Links databases into SPS configuration Core to Web.

I made the change and after that, I am continuously getting errors -

In browser console I can see  - `/sitecore/api/ssc/publishing/maintenance/0/IsRunning` - Response status code does not indicate success: `502 (Bad Gateway)`.

And on Publish window and Publishing Dashboard getting  - Publishing Service not working Contact Administrator.

I am changing back to Core it again start working but Publish Related Items not working in this case.

Anyone faced any similar issue with SPS? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: did you try by enabling the "sc.publishing.relateditems.xml" at `sitecorepublishing\config\sitecore\publishing`?

Comment: Yes I did... didn't work

Comment: Is it not working after full republish? SPS does not publish items if one of their parents is not published.

Comment: @x3mxray - No It is not working if I am publishing Single Item with Options Selected Publish Related Items ... in this case it is not publishing related items

Comment: @YogeshSharma, have you found what the problem was? We're facing similar issue.

Comment: @grg - See my comment on https://community.sitecore.net/developers/f/8/t/11120

Answer (score 2):

Sitecore stores Links database/table to Core db in On-Premise environment, but in a scaled environment, it stores Links table to **Web** database.
By default, "Publishing Service" points to **Core** database so you need to change this setting to **Web**.

File: In sitecore publishing webApp: *sitecorepublishing\config\sitecore\publishing\sc.publishing.xml*

```
<DefaultConnectionFactory>
      <Options>
        <Connections>
          <Links>
          <Type>Sitecore.Framework.Publishing.Data.AdoNet.SqlDatabaseConnection, Sitecore.Framework.Publishing.Data</Type>
            <LifeTime>Transient</LifeTime>
            <Options>
              <ConnectionString>${Sitecore:Publishing:ConnectionStrings:Web}</ConnectionString>
              <DefaultCommandTimeout>120</DefaultCommandTimeout>
              <Behaviours>
                <backend>sql-backend-default</backend>
                <api>sql-api-default</api>
              </Behaviours>
            </Options>
          </Links>
```

You can refer **Sitecore.Config** file to verify your CM configuration.

```
<sc.variable name="defaultLinkDatabaseConnectionStringName" value="core" />
  <sc.variable name="defaultLinkDatabaseConnectionStringName" role:require="ContentDelivery or ContentManagement">
    <patch:attribute name="value">web</patch:attribute>
  </sc.variable>
```

---

```
<LinkDatabase type="Sitecore.Data.$(database).$(database)LinkDatabase, Sitecore.Kernel">
<param connectionStringName="$(defaultLinkDatabaseConnectionStringName)" />
```

Finally enable file "sc.publishing.relateditems.xml" at sitecorepublishing\config\sitecore\publishing

Note 1: You might face issue with schema after making above changes, so in order to resolve that issue you need to re-run update schema command again, irrespective of previous schema state,

Command 1:.\Sitecore.Framework.Publishing.Host.exe schema list

Command 2:.\Sitecore.Framework.Publishing.Host.exe schema upgrade --force

Note 2: Authors must select the Publish Related items checkbox before publishing.

Note 3: Sitecore only publishes those related items, which are referenced by the selected item, but not those, which refer to that selected item.